# Remove a specific character from a string to make INSERT accept string with quotes

Tags: c#, mysql

Not sure this question has been asked before though. If it were, my apologies.

I need to remove an apostrophe character from a string.

The reason for this has to be done because it's triggering an error in the SQL query for client's name which I fetch from the local database.

The error indicates near the 'apostrophe s'.

When I remove that data field from the local database error ain't appear.

I came up with a solution for removing the apostrophe character from the client name.

I tried to use Remove() function but it only works for integers. (string to int conversion error).

My code is as follows:

```
while (rdr.Read())
            {
                 int promised_date = (int)(rdr.GetValue(0));
```

> string strClientName = (rdr.GetValue(1).ToString());

```
                string strClientReference = (rdr.GetValue(2).ToString());
                string strJobCategory = (rdr.GetValue(3).ToString());
                string datCommisioned = (rdr.GetValue(4).ToString());
                string datPromisedDelivery = (rdr.GetValue(5).ToString());


                  if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                    {
                        string querynew = "INSERT INTO jobs_table (nJobNumber,strClientName,strClientReference,strJobCategory,datCommisioned,datPromisedDelivery) VALUES ("+promised_date+",'"+strClientName+"','"+strClientReference+"','"+strJobCategory+"','"+datCommisioned+"','"+datPromisedDelivery+"' )";//yeyyy why only few?

                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(querynew, connection);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                      this.CloseConnection();
                    }
              }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to remove the apostrophe from strClientName when reading the data?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use parameters.

Comment: No No No.  Rather than changing the data to make it "safe", use SQL Parameters to pass the data.  That has not been the correct way to compose SQL for a long time

Comment: What's the client called, [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: if its the same database you can use an INSERT into SELECT call, do it all at once and not inside a loop at all...you have an openconnection/closeconnection in a reader loop which is odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use parameters.  You can read more about here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    int promised_date = (int)(rdr.GetValue(0));
    string strClientName = (rdr.GetValue(1).ToString());
    string strClientReference = (rdr.GetValue(2).ToString());
    string strJobCategory = (rdr.GetValue(3).ToString());
    string datCommisioned = (rdr.GetValue(4).ToString());
    string datPromisedDelivery = (rdr.GetValue(5).ToString());

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)//closing parenthesis
    {
        // query using parameter names 
        string querynew = "INSERT INTO jobs_table "
                          + "(nJobNumber,strClientName,strClientReference,strJobCategory,datCommisioned,datPromisedDelivery)" 
                          + "VALUES (@PromisedDate, @ClientName, @ClientReference, @JobCategory, @Commisioned, @PromisedDelivery)";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(querynew, connection);

        // add parameters and their value
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDate", promised_date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", strClientName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientReference", strClientReference);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobCategory", strJobCategory);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Commissioned", datCommissioned);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDelivery", datPromisedDelivery);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: **[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)**

Comment: You're a living legend my man! @STLDeveloper

Comment: Ryan, @Plutonix makes a good point. You should consider following his advice.  Click on his answer and it will link you to an article on why it's not always great to use `Parmeters.AddWithValue()`.  Assuming you know the database field data types, you should probably instead use `Parameters.Add()` using appropriate data types.